# Can I combine maybe's (rx)?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java

Can I combine `Maybes` in a way that `combineLatest` combines `Observables`

basically:
    -make a new `Maybe` that waits for a list of `Maybes` to have emission and then make a new `Maybe` that emits one item (that is a combination of the list of `Maybes`)

P.S. I can provide actual code where i have to implement this

Comment: It is called [`Maybe.zip`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#zip-java.lang.Iterable-io.reactivex.functions.Function-). Does RxJS even have `Maybe`?

Comment: I'd try http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html#mergeArray-io.reactivex.MaybeSource...-